# M1 MacBook Air: Change resolution to 1920x1200 pixels

Tags: macbook-pro, resolution, apple-silicon

How can I change the resolution of my **M1 MacBook Air** (Silicon Version) to **1920x1200** pixels?

I tried so many softwares like QuickRes, SwitchResX and some other softwares/scripts from github. But nothing is working with the new M1 version. I can get **2048x1280**, but I specifically need  **1920x1200** this resolution.

Similar type question is asked in apple forum, but it looks like there is no working solution yet. Link below:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/668252

Comment: Do you mean an external display or the built-in screen of the M1-MBA?

Comment: Presumably, you want a SCALED resolution of 1920: e.g. with a 1.3333 scale factor from the full display's 2560. Have you tried the old trick of pressing Alt/Option when you press the "Scaled" radio button?

Comment: @SteveChambers I mean the built-in screen of the M1-MBA. Although I can get the desired resolution when I connect an external display. But I want that resolution too (1920X1200) when I don't connect an external display.

Comment: Understood, thx. SwitchResX is a handy little utility that allow you to switch the resolution of all displays to a variety of options that Apple does not offer. I think there is a free trial, perhaps worth checking out.

Comment: @AsifReza Were you able to find a solution? I need a resolution of 1920x1080 but SwitchResX and EasyRes don't have that.

Comment: @multigoodverse Hey, sorry for the late reply! Nope, I don't find any solution to this yet! I'm just using an external monitor to achieve this resolution at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

Current version of SwitchResX (4.12.1) works for mba m1 2020.

Answer (score 1):

Since that's such a bad (fractional pixels / blurry) scaling factor, I would virtualize macOS if I absolutely needed that exact scale for screen shots or some other reason.

- https://blog.mobinergy.com/how-to-virtualize-macos-ventura-on-mac-with-apple-sillicon-chip-the-easy-way/

The article describes Ventura beta, but should work for Monterey with some slight fixes.